# openssl certificate chain - windows

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I have a *ROOT_CA* and a *subCA*. The *subCA* issued a certificate for a website (*CUPS1.local*). Moreover I have Windows clients; the *ROOT_CA* is already installed as *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*.

Validating the *subCA* works using `openssl verify` and also I can see it in Windows.

I can also verfiy the certificate for *CUPS1.local* in openssl via

```
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/certs/cacert.pem -untrusted subCA_websites.crt cups1.crt
cups1.crt: OK
```

Moreover, if I create a chain the certificate is also OK

```
cat /etc/certs/cacert.pem subCA_websites.crt > chain.pem
openssl verify -CAfile chain.pem cups1.crt
cups1.crt: OK
```

Now, I also want Windows to see these certificates as valid. And here is the problem:
Windows does not see the certificate chain:

[image: without SUB_CA certificate]

However, after installing the certificate of the *subCA*, the certificate for *CUPS1.local* is valid.

[image]

Hence, maybe I misunderstood some basics: Do I need to install the certificate of every *subCA* as *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*? Is there another way to implement the certificate chain into the certificate for *CUPS1.local*, such that I only need to install the *ROOT_CA* and not all the *subCAs*?

**Short update**:
Well, since the certificate was intended for a website (CUPS server) the chain works by combining:

```
cat cups1.crt subCA_websites.crt /etc/certs/cacert.pem > chain.crt
```

When I add this `chain.crt` to the CUPS server (and also the key-file), I can open the website without error message. I do not need to install the *subCA* certificate, only the *ROOT_CA* is fine.

Anyway, out of curiosity I would like to understand if windows can also somehow read the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to install the certificate of every subCA as Trusted Root Certification Authorities?

no, only root CA certificate is installed to Trusted Root CAs store. Intermediate CA certificates go to Intermediate CAs store.

> Is there another way to implement the certificate chain into the certificate for CUPS1.local, such that I only need to install the ROOT_CA and not all the subCAs?

yes, just implement Authority Information Access in CAs and CA-issued certificates that will have URLs to obtain all required certificates.

> Anyway, out of curiosity I would like to understand if windows can also somehow read the chain?

Windows fully supports X.509 chains, however the implementation is a bit different than in Linux, for example. Windows DOES NOT support concatenated multiple PEM certificates in a file. Instead, additional certificates must be supplied via:

- locally installed certificates in Windows Certificate Store
- PKCS#7 message
- Authority Information Access certificate extension

Comment: If you want to convert a PEM concatenated chain on Linux to a PKCS7 message for windows, you can do it via OpenSSL:

`openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile input_chain.pem -out input_chain.pem.p7b`

Answer (score 1):

> Anyway, out of curiosity I would like to understand if windows can also somehow read the chain?

There is no "**somehow** read the chain". Either it has the necessary chain certificates or it does not. It can have the certificates if they are provided up-front (i.e. installed locally) or if they are provided during verification. The latter is the common case, i.e. it is expected that the web server actually provides all necessary chain certificates along with the server certificate during TLS handshake.

If the chain certificates are missing **some implementations might try to fill in the missing chain certificates** for validation. For example Firefox caches chain certificates seen on past websites and then tries to use these cached certificates to fill in missing chain certificates. This works pretty well for public websites since the trusted root CA only use a small set of chain certificates. Chrome also tries to extract the URL of a missing chain certificates from *Authority Information Access | CA Issuers* information in a certificate and then loads missing issuer certificates from the given URL.